# W3C validation failed and 404 error when using angular with image

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular and I have the following:

```
<img src="{{image.Url}}" alt="" />
```

When I validate with W3C I get the following:

Bad value {{image.Url}} for attribute src on element img: Illegal character in path segment: not a URL code point.

And I also get an 404 error until the value is replaced by angular.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution:

```
<img src="http://1x1px.me/FFFFFF-0.png" ng-src="{{image.Url}}" alt="" />
```

Now the images uses a transparent PNG until its src in not replaced by angular.

It validates and no 404 error anymore.